# How to create a histogram chart in vs C# 2010?

Tags: c#, charts

I'm trying to create a histogram chart in c # (vs 2010) however I'm not getting. How to add new graphs in C #?

I'm using the chart control, however there is no histogram.

The graph uses intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RangeColumn` chart type.

```
standardSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeColumn;
standardSeries.BorderWidth = 1;
standardSeries.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
standardSeries.BorderColor = Color.Black;
standardSeries.Color = Color.Blue;
```

Each point in the chart then represents one bin of the histogram.

Comment: It continues to create columns, how do I get united?

Comment: Each column is a `DataPoint`, which corresponds to a bin in your histogram. If you don't want any more columns, don't add any more `DataPoints` What do you mean by getting it united?

Comment: ![histogram](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_1TJIU2FVZgg/TO-_Y3G1KoI/AAAAAAAAAAo/nPXyYIXOFn0/s1600/histograma.jpg)

Comment: Plese look at the image.